# Laravel Eloquent - This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I was able to create groups by geography and country, it worked well (see image attachment)[image]

Controller

```
$table_companies = Clients::selectRaw('geography geography, country country')->groupBy('geography', 'country')->get()->toArray();
return view('about.our-clients', compact('our-clients','table_companies'));
```

View

```
@foreach ($table_companies as $geography)
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12 text-center" 
            style="color:#000000">
          <h2 class="bigFont text-center">
             {{ $geography['geography'] }}
          </h2>
       </div>

     @foreach ($table_companies as $country)
       <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding:25px 0">
          <h2 class="text-center" 
              style="background-color:#000000;
                     color:#ffffff;
                     font-size:1.4em;padding:5px 0;">  
              {{ $country['country'] }}
          </h2>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="row">
              <!--Company names will be loaded here-->
          </div>
       </div>
     @endforeach
  </div>
  <br><br>
@endforeach
```

The problem begins when I try to get the company names

Controller

```
$table_companies = Clients::selectRaw('geography geography, country country, name_company company')->groupBy('geography', 'country', 'company')->get()->toArray();
```

View

```
@foreach ($table_companies as $geography)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" class="text-center" style="color:#000000">
          <h2 class="bigFont text-center">
             {{ $geography['geography'] }}
         </h2>
        </div>
    @foreach ($table_companies as $country)
      <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding:25px 0">
        <h2 class="text-center" 
            style="background-color:#000000;
                   color:#ffffff;
                   font-size: 1.4em;
                   padding:5px 0;">
         {{ $country['country'] }}
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($table_companies as $companies)
              <div class="col-sm-4">{{ $companies['company'] }}</div>
            @endforeach 
            </div>
          </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to use plain vanilla php to render the page and group things they way I wanted. Thank you.